# Force svn up before commits

Tags: svn, version-control

I have been using svn fast and furious to do commits and, because I'm airhead, I can't seem to remember to to "svn up" before my commits.
Does anyone know of a way in svn to enforce an "svn up" before doing a commit? I'm using svn on Ubuntu.
Many thanks!
Janie

Comment: What's the point? If there are conflicts, svn won't let you commit. Otherwise... just train your brain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an alias for yourself in your shell. Something like this:

```
svnci = svn up;svn ci
```

Or even a small shell script in your $`PATH`

But how will you manage merge conflicts and compilation errors when this happens?

`svn commit` should not allow you to commit (well, the server shouldn't) unless your working copy is already up to the `HEAD` revision anyway. So in your current state, the worst that should be happening is your commit is rejected by the server.